# How to suppress echos in makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following PHONY target in Makefile

```
install: 
        echo /usr/bin/shelldecrypt must be writable
        cp shelldecrypt /usr/bin
```

When I run the target it displays the command it is executing

**prompt> make install**

*OUTPUT IS*

```
    echo /usr/bin/shelldecrypt must be writable 
    /usr/bin/shelldecrypt must be writable
    cp shelldecrypt /usr/bin
```

*OUTPUT AS I WOULD LIKE IT*

```
    /usr/bin/shelldecrypt must be writable
    cp shelldecrypt /usr/bin
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could add "@" before your command to surpress that echo

```
install: 
        @echo /usr/bin/shelldecrypt must be writable
        cp shelldecrypt /usr/bin
```