# What is the leading "@" at the recipe of a makefile

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make, recipe

In a makefile that is generated by eclipse, I see the following rules:

```
./Cores/$(TARGET).core.3.srec : ../$(TARGET).core.3/Debug/$(TARGET).core.3.elf
        @mkdir -p ./Cores/
        @e-objcopy --srec-forceS3 --output-target srec "$<" "$@".temp
        @echo Creating srec file for CoreID\<0x826\>
        @head --lines=1 "$@".temp  | sed 's/0000/0826/' > "$@"
        @tail --lines=+2 "$@".temp >> "$@"
```

What is the purpose of the "**@**" at the beginning of the recipe lines?

Reading through the GNU Make user's manual I could not find a reference to this use of @. I then assumed that it is actually transferred as-is to the shell.

So, reading the BASH manual, the only place I could relate to this use is in command substitution when the `extglob` option is set. However, trying this in the command line gave me an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@` prefix causes make to run the command silently. See [this section of the GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing).

Comment: Thanks! So, is it a make command or a shell command (modifier/directive)?

Answer (score 2):

The @ suppresses echoing the command when running the recipe, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/867093/60462.

Comment: Thanks! So, is it a make command or a shell command (modifier/directive)?

Comment: It's `make` syntax alone. Or did `@ls` ever give you a directory listing?