# gnu make: prerequisite is always called even when target has not changed

Tags: build, npm, makefile

I'm new to make, coming from npm. I'm trying to use them together which works pretty well. Only make seem to think that it needs to run a certain npm command every time, but the target files are there and unchanged.

I got a website for a project in git. The website has a git submodule to this project, called npm. The only thing that is important in this, is that I need to build some files in that directory and zip them to the root of the website. The website does not have a package.json so npm will not work in that directory.

Below is the MakeFile and at the end is my questions.

```
REPO_FOLDER = npm
MINI_FILES = stream.min.js stream.min.js.map
#STREAM_MINI_FILES := $(REPO_FOLDER)/stream.min.js $(REPO_FOLDER)/stream.min.js.map
STREAM_MINI_FILES := $(MINI_FILES:%=REPO_FOLDER/%) #6.3.1 Substitution References

stream.js.zip: $(STREAM_MINI_FILES)
    cd $(REPO_FOLDER); \
    npm run zip ../stream.js.zip $(MINI_FILES)

$(STREAM_MINI_FILES): minify

minify:
    @cd $(REPO_FOLDER); \
    test -d "node_modules" || npm install; \
    npm run minify;

update:
    @git submodule update --remote

all: update stream.js.zip

.PHONY: minify, update, all
```

1) The minify target is always run even though npm/stream.min.js npm/stream.min.js.map are there. Why is that and how can I get make to recognize these two files?

2) What is the difference between `@cd` and `cd`? In the minify target I can `@cd` to the npm folder and run `npm install`, but in the stream.js.zip target, I get an error from npm because it is still in the website directory (without a package.json). Why am I not in the npm directory, when I do @cd in that case?

3) I use npm to zip the two compiled files. I have seen that there is a `ar` command in make, but can it make a zip file and if yes, how?

***update***
It turns out that my variable substitution was wrong and hence the second target was wrong as well. $(STREAM_MINI_FILES) would resolve to `REPO_FOLDER/stream.min.js` `REPO_FOLDER/stream.min.js.map` instead of `stream/stream.min.js` `stream/stream.min.js.map`. Since the prerequisite in the first rule, with **REPO_FOLDER** never existed, make would run the second rule's recipe every time.

Here is the final working MakeFile:

```
REPO_FOLDER = stream
MINI_FILES = stream.min.js stream.min.js.map
ZIP_FILE = stream.js.zip 
#STREAM_MINI_FILES := $(REPO_FOLDER)/stream.min.js $(REPO_FOLDER)/stream.min.js.map
STREAM_MINI_FILES := $(MINI_FILES:%=$(REPO_FOLDER)/%) #6.3.1 Substitution References


$(ZIP_FILE): $(STREAM_MINI_FILES)
    @cd $(REPO_FOLDER); \
    npm run zip ../$@ $(MINI_FILES)

$(STREAM_MINI_FILES):
    @cd $(REPO_FOLDER); \
    test -d "node_modules" || npm install; \
    npm run minify;


update:
    @git submodule update --remote

clean:
    @rm --verbose $(ZIP_FILE) $(STREAM_MINI_FILES)

all: update $(ZIP_FILE)

.PHONY: update, clean, all
```

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: #2 is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708537/what-is-the-leading-at-the-recipe-of-a-makefile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) `minify` is declared as a prerequisite of the `.PHONY` special target. make rebuilds it every time another target depending on it must be built or make is called with this goal. If you invoke make with `make` (that is, without specifying a goal) it will try to build the first target in the makefile, `stream.js.zip`, in your case. As it depends on `$(STREAM_MINI_FILES)`, make will first check whether these are up-to-date or not and rebuild them if they are not. `$(STREAM_MINI_FILES)` themselves depend on `minify`, which is a prerequisite of `.PHONY` and must thus be remade in every case, even if a file named `minify` exists and is up-to-date.

Moreover, I suspect `minify` is a symbolic target and there is no real file with this name (am I wrong?). This is another reason why make would rebuild it: it does not exist but it is required by `$(STREAM_MINI_FILES)`.

One option would be to remove `minify` completely (including from the `.PHONY` prerequisites) and merge the rules:

```
$(STREAM_MINI_FILES):
    @cd $(REPO_FOLDER); \
    test -d "node_modules" || npm install; \
    npm run minify
```

This should run the recipe only if one of the files listed in `$(STREAM_MINI_FILES)` is missing. One drawback is that the recipe will be run as many times as there are missing files, which is a waste. To avoid this you can keep your `minify` target but make it a real empty file that keeps track of what has been done already:

```
$(STREAM_MINI_FILES): minify

minify:
    @cd $(REPO_FOLDER); \
    test -d "node_modules" || npm install; \
    npm run minify
    touch $@
```

This is a very common trick that proves very useful every time your build process is not exactly something like "take one source file and build one result file".

2) With `command` in a recipe, make echoes the command when executing it. `@command` suppresses the echoing. It has nothing to do with your problem, I guess.

The list of commands in a make recipe are executed by make with one separate process per line. So, if you:

```
cd there
pwd
```

the two lines are executed in two different processes and the first one has no effect on the second. Putting your commands on the same bash list, that is, separating the commands by `;` forces make to execute them in a single process (the `\` as last character on a line escapes the end-of-line character):

```
cd there; pwd
```

or:

```
cd there; \
pwd
```

are equivalent and will execute the `pwd` command in the `there` directory. In your `stream.js.zip` recipe, you have a single bash list. So, it should work as expected and the second member of the list should be executed from the `$(REPO_FOLDER)` directory. Your problem comes from something else. Did you try to run the command manually? Did you check that the `\` is really the last character on the line (else it does not escape the end-of-line).

3) `ar` is not a make command. It is a GNU archive utility. And no, it cannot make a zip archive which is a different format. Note that make can operate on the internals of `ar` archives as if they were unpacked, which can be useful. Type `man ar` to know more about `ar`.

Comment: 1) yes you're right. `minify` does not exist. I just want make to run minify if $(STREAM_MINI_FILES) is missing. If they do exist, then I don't want make to run minify. Apparently I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: I see. Why don't you merge the two rules, suppress the `minify` target and use its recipe for `$(STREAM_MINI_FILES)`?

Comment: Using the variable `$(STREAM_MINI_FILES)`, which contains two files, runs the recipe twice. And still on every call to make.

Comment: 2) You're right again. I don't know what when wrong and got fixed but it was coincidental with removing the echo suppress symbol (@).

Comment: 1) I edited my answer to show you how to avoid the double build for `$(STREAM_MINI_FILES)`. But anyway, with my suggestion of merging the two rules make should not run the recipe on every invocation, unless one or the two files listed in `$(STREAM_MINI_FILES)` are missing. If it does, there is something else that you do not show and that forces this. Did you change the prerequisites of `.PHONY`?

Comment: I've updated the question with the new MakeFile I made with your suggestion about merging the two rules. I'll try your work around tomorrow.

Comment: My variable substitution is wrong. `STREAM_MINI_FILES := $(MINI_FILES:%=REPO_FOLDER/%)`. I thought I would get `$(REPO_FOLDER)/stream.min.js` but I literally get `REPO_FOLDER/stream.min.js`

Comment: The correct way is: `STREAM_MINI_FILES := $(MINI_FILES:%=$(REPO_FOLDER)/%)`

Comment: It doesn't actually do `npm run minify` twice using GNU Make 3.81. Just once as expected. You made a very comprehensive answer and I thank you for that. I also want to thank you for doing diligent updates to fix my main issue. But in the process, the answer is a bit clotted. Perhaps cleanup of 1) would serve the next viewers better.

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, I will see how to rework my answer so that it is still in line with your updated questions. I am a bit surprised that `npm run minify` is run only once with your final version. Are you sure of that? Did you `make clean all`?

Comment: The output of doing `make` is http://pastebin.com/Skkejyrn Before (when the path was wrong) I was seeing two instances of ` stream.js@1.0.1 minify...`, now I only see one. I have tested it by deleting `make clean`, only deleting the zip file and deleting both STREAM_MINI_FILES files or just one of them. In all instances the make script act as expected.

Comment: The reason why it doesn't run twice is because (on my OS), make run tasks consecutive. If I supply the `-j 2` argument, it runs it twice. Your `touch` workaround is very valid in that case.